# How to detect renames in Tortoise HG Workbench

Tags: tortoisehg

I had a significant number of files in my project just on the root level so I decided to clean them up by placing them into folders for Manager classes, API classes etc. When I go into Tortoise HG's workbench, I see that is thinks I have removed all of these files and added them (with the folder extensions). I see on the "add" items there is an option to detect name changes so I click it but it doesn't seem to be able to find anything (even when dropping the similarity to 0)

How can I "find" these files to avoid an ugly commit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you moved the items they should have become unknown `?` (pink). Right click on one and choose "Detect Renames".

It only works for unknown files, and only will match with files of status `!` missing.

Once it finds a match it turns the rename into an `A` add and an `R` remove. If you click on one of the added files you will see "renamed from..." in the diff pane.

Comment: Cheers. Looks like Visual Studio managed that for me. I just thought it should have come up with a Rename sort of change in HG rather than a remove and add